# Installing PEAR, IIS Problem

Tags: php, iis, pear

I installed PHP with Web Platform Installer. Now I need to install PEAR but installation documantation of Pear is saying that

> you have to manually execute the batch
>   file located in e.g.
>   c:\php\go-pear.bat

PHP folder isn't in c:, it is located in C:\Program Files\PHP and there isn't any file named "go-pear.php"..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved :)...

I realize that I have add it from the installer (changing features)..

Comment: You realize what? I have the same problem, but don't understand how you solved it.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old, but it still features in search engine results. And the self-reply above is unhelpful.

In Summary:

1. Download http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar to somewhere writable.
2. Copy it, using Explorer to `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3`
3. Fire up a command console with full privileges
4. Change to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3` folder
5. Run the command: `php.exe -q go-pear.phar`

Note: when changing default paths using the installer, the first time you use the file browser, it works. Subsequent usages (say to change another folder) fails and returns with an error. I had to Ctrl+C the install and just use the defaults.

My environment: Win-764, IIS (not IISExpress), and PHP 5.3.13 as installed by WebPI.

I later found some instructions (and similar page discussions) at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

Note: Downloading the go-pear version does not work on this setup (sorry link removed due to low rep restriction).

Answer (score -2):

Exactly, from the plarform web installer there is no option for adding the phar

Comment: This isnt very helpful, the answer from @Mayyit is better.